# Google cartographer-ros 3D slam empty map problem

Tags: ros, slam, ros-melodic, hector-localization, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to adapt the bagpack_3d tutorial of cartographer ROS to a sick laser scanner with an imu.
The scanner and imu are working. However with the current setup, I do not get any localization/map (empty /submap_list).
So basically somewhere in the \cartographer_node there is an error.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

My configuration file looks like this:

```
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"
options = {
  map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
  trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "imu_link",
  published_frame = "base_link",
  odom_frame = "odom",
  provide_odom_frame = true,
  publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
  use_odometry = false,
  use_nav_sat = false,
  use_landmarks = false,
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
  num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,
  num_point_clouds = 0,
  lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
  submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
  pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
  trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
  rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
}
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D.num_accumulated_range_data = 160
MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_3d = true
MAP_BUILDER.num_background_threads = 7
POSE_GRAPH.optimization_problem.huber_scale = 5e2
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 320
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.sampling_ratio = 0.03
POSE_GRAPH.optimization_problem.ceres_solver_options.max_num_iterations = 10
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.min_score = 0.62
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.global_localization_min_score = 0.66
return options
```

In comparison to the backpack tutorial (with 2 velodyne scanners), I have a simple horizontal lidar.
Accordingly, I have changed the parameters:

```
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_point_clouds = 0
```

To create the tf, we call the robot urdf file with the robot state publisher in the launchfile

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find robot_navigation)/urdf/robot_3d.urdf" />

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <node name="cartographer_node" pkg="cartographer_ros"
      type="cartographer_node" args="
          -configuration_directory $(find robot_navigation)/configuration_files
          -configuration_basename robot_3d.lua"
      output="screen">
   <remap from="imu" to="imu/data_raw" />
   <remap from="scan" to="sick_s300_laser/scan" />
  </node>

  <node name="cartographer_occupancy_grid_node" pkg="cartographer_ros"
      type="cartographer_occupancy_grid_node" args="-resolution 0.05" />
</launch>
```

My major question:
Do you have any idea, why I do not get any localization/map?

My minor question:
As I am using the melodic binary version:
sudo apt install ros-melodic-cartographer-ros
Using the debugger from visual studio code with ROS plugin, I can launch the cartographer, but pausing the debugger does not work/give me any address in the binaries. Do you have a good idea how to debug the binary ros packages?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316997/google-cartographer-ros-3d-slam-empty-map-problem/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2019-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-28**:
You miss the tf `odom`, you seem to have removed it from your previous question ([#q316747](https://answers.ros.org/question/316747/cartographer-slam-tf-tree-errors/)) that might be the issue. Also you have the param `use_odometry` set to false, is it intended ?

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-02-28**:
The tf odom was actually not wanted, as it was provided by the pervious IMU filter. What I would like to have is that the cartographer computes the odom based on the laser and imu measurements. I think "use_odometry" should be negative here as I don't want to impose an externally calculated odom.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-03-02**:
lua params seems good. but transfrom time from the tf pic, are 0.0, this will affect the transformation calculation. pls check

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-03-02**:
Hi, thanks for your help. Isn't it normal that the tf time is 0.0, as those are static transformations?

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-03-04**:
its abnormal. tf is broadcasting to the system and no one knows that it is a static transform. It is just like a common tf, should have a proper time stamp.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-03-04**:
if possible pls indicate whats print on the terminal,any warning like tf_old_data?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-04**:
I disagree with you on that. Since the broadcaster is `/robot_state_publisher` that means `base_laser_link` and `imu_link` are defined in the urdf. When you have fixed joint then you have this kind of output in the tf tree so that's just show that those two tfs are fixed to `base_link` .

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-03-07**:
Hi, thanks for your input. As I still couldn't get any result, I opened the issue:
https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_ros/issues/1217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was not with cartographer_ros, but has been a negative time-increment in the laser scanner msg.

---

Originally posted by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) with karma: 170 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jona](https://answers.ros.org/users/45285/jona/) on 2019-08-31**:
Hi, How did you find that it was teh cause and how did you solve it?

**Comment by [Mohit Arvind Khakharia](https://answers.ros.org/users/38621/mohit-arvind-khakharia/) on 2020-11-02**:
@Jona
You get a message like this if you are playing a rosbag on a loop, when you cross the starting point.